# Python, regex dynamic count

Tags: python, regex

So far I have this code:

```
def find_words(m_count, m_string):
    m_list = re.findall(r'\w{6,}', m_string)
    return m_list
```

is there a way to use `m_count` instead of using the count number (6) explicitly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a regex by concatenating your count variable and static part like this:

```
>>> m_count = 6
>>> re.findall(r'\w{' + str(m_count) + ',}', 'abcdefg 1234 124xyz')
['abcdefg', '124xyz']
```

Comment: For those who might be using PyCharm, if you face "pattern expected" error, you can define the pattern on a different line (pattern = r'\w{' + str(m_count) + ',}') and then use the pattern directly (re.findall(pattern, 'abcdefg 1234 124xyz'))

Answer (score 2):

Convert the int to string and added to you reg exp like this:

```
def find_words(m_count, m_string):
    m_list = re.findall(r'\w{'+str(m_count)+',}', m_string)
    return m_list
```

Comment: If you notice I had [same answer posted 5-6 minutes ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39043542/548225) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), and [*escape*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) the curly braces.

```
>>> import re
>>> m_count = 6
>>> print re.findall(r'\w{{{},}}'.format(m_count),'123456789 foobar hello_world')
['123456789', 'hello_world']
```

**Full method body:**

```
def find_words(m_count, m_string):
    m_list = re.findall(r'\w{{{},}}'.format(m_count), m_string)
    return m_list
```